# ng-repeat inside Custom Angular Directive Not Working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, directive

I am attempting to build what should be a very simple custom directive using some hierarchical data. Each page in the list has subpages and the data is of the form:

```
{"Title 1": "Page Title", "Id": "1", "Pages": {"Title 1.1": "Page Title 1.1", "Id": "2"}, {"Title 1.2": "Page Title 1.2", "Id": "3"}}
```

and so on.  The data here is just a quick illustration - there is no issue with either the data or retrieval method.

I have a directive controller set up as:

```
app.directive('pageSelectList', function () {
return {
    restrict: 'EA',
    replace: true,
    scope: {
        pageList: '='
    },
    templateUrl: '/Scripts/App/Directives/Templates/PageSelectList.html',
    link: function (scope, elem, attrs) { }
   };
});
```

The template is:

```
<ul class="page-list page-root">
    <li ng-repeat="p in pageList.Pages">{{ p.Title }}</li>
</ul>
```

The directive is used with data drawn from the parent scope (`$scope.listOfPages`).

However, when using it, nothing is displayed - it's blank.  Strangely, when replacing the directive template with the following markup:

```
<p>{{ pageList.Title }}</p>
```

The expected markup `<p>Title 1</p>` is shown.

It would appear that the directive has some sort of issue with either `ng-repeat` or that the data being used in the repeat is a subobject of the `pageList` object passed.

Furthermore, when the markup for the directive is just used in a regular page with data from the parent scope, there is no problem at all. It seems to be a problem with the directive itself.

**EDIT**

This is the page controller that is populating the data for the directive:

```
var pageEditController = function ($scope, $rootScope, $state, $stateParams, pageService) {
$scope.page = {};
$scope.errorMessage = "";

getPage(); // This is for other data on the page and not directly linked to directive issue.

getPages(); // This is to get the directive data

function getPage() { // Just an http get method for $scope.page }}

function getPages() {
    pageService.getTree()
        .success(function (result) {
            $scope.pageList = result.Result; // This is where the directive data is loaded into scope
        })
        .error(function (error) {
            $scope.errorMessage = 'Unable to load pages';
        });
     };

});
```

**Further strange behaviour:**

A template with this:

`<p>{{ pageList.Title }}</p>`

shows the Title OK.

This:

`<p>{{ pageList.Title }}</p><p>{{ pageList.Id }}</p>`

shows nothing at all. Obviously ng-repeat in original example doesn't work either.

Comment: could you provide the code you're actually using?

Comment: How are you calling the 'pageSelectList' directive?

Comment: do you see any errors in console? except not valid JSON in OP - your code seems work

Comment: can you provide plunkr? and sample value for `pageList`?

Comment: working sample for your code: http://plnkr.co/edit/Jit4Qraq05DC6drcxTXR?p=preview you just have not `Title` property

Comment: Unfortunately still not working.  I'll add the page controller in the OP

Comment: @Graham, can you provide plunkr where you can show what indeed not working?

Comment: Plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/0SESiP2YKQQzNz1gXcOO?p=preview

Comment: just see error in console: _Error: [$compile:tplrt] Template for directive 'pageSelectList' must have exactly one root element. PageSelectList.html_,  [here fixed plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/NZKjcZQ3GciCc4r6GSMi?p=preview) all work fine

Comment: more about this error in doc: https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$compile/tplrt?p0=pageSelectList&p1=PageSelectList.html

Comment: @Grundy - can you add as an answer and I'll confirm it as such. Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As we detect in comment: your code work OK, and problem with template for directive.

When you use `replace:true` in your directive, template that you load *must have exactly one root element* otherwise you get next error:

> Error: [$compile:tplrt] Template for directive 'pageSelectList' must have exactly one root element. PageSelectList.html
>   https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$compile/tplrt?p0=pageSelectList&p1=PageSelectList.html

So, for solving you have two way:

1) wrap your template in container, like a `div`

```
<div>
    your directive 
    <p>{{ pageList.Title }}</p><p>{{ pageList.Id }}</p>
</div>
```

2) remove flag `replace`, or use it `replace: false`.

Answer (score 1):

In the directive, you have mentioned as "pageList". But in the template, you are accessing it using "PageList". So, I guess that it may solve using issue.